# Php create new array from array value if the array have same value

Tags: php, arrays

Example I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 7
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 9
)
```

And my question is, how to create new array like this. So create new array for the same value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
        )

    [2] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
)
```

Please help me and sory for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_count_values($array) as $value => $occurrences) {
    $result[] = $occurrences == 1 ? $value : array_fill(0, $occurrences, $value);
}
```

See http://php.net/array_count_values. In fact, this may really be what you're looking for; I don't see the point in repeating the same value many times.

Comment: Thanks @deceze... very thanks :)
But how if same value not only 1, example 1,1,1 and 5,5,5. This code is same?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  using  `array_count_values`

```
<?php

$tr = Array(1,1,1,1,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$array= array_count_values($tr);
var_dump($array);


$arry1 = array();
foreach($array as $key =>$val){
 if ($val>1){
     $tmp =array();
     for($i= 0;$i<$val;$i++){
       $tmp[] =$key;
     }
     $arry1[] =$tmp;
 }
 else{
     $arry1[] =$key;
 } 
}

var_dump( $arry1);
?>
```